# How to calculate a tangent line for a given point in painter path?

Tags: qt, geometry

Given a generic `QPainterPath` and a generic `QPointF` contained by the path how can one calculate a tangent line on that point? There's no standard way to do that with Qt API and my search lead me to no results...

Comment: This task is not correct in common case, the knowledge of point does not give you possibility to calculate tangent line in 2 fallowing cases: derivative doesn't exist in that point or more then 1 curve passes through that point. More, `QPainterPath` is a 'view', you shouldn't try obtaining data from it

Comment: Lol4t0: I'm trying to draw a simple spline line (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) as an edge for node connections. Whenever I curve the edge the arrow's angle on the line's tip changes, so I need to redefine it. How can I know the angle for the arrow if I can't determine the tangent on the fixing point?

Comment: Rizo: You can operate parameterized curve. You can get known tangent for any value of parameter t using `angleAtPercent`. Tips have values `0` and `1` for `t`

Comment: Also, if you draw a spline as a number of line segments, you can get incorrect result